# Why did I fail this audit by trying to edit the post?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22846176

The answer is not formatted properly, and hence I wanted to edit it.

The problem I guess here is that the answer contains a link to author's article. but what is the harm in it if it is free and it helps?

[image]
The question is about how to do Put Requests, and the answer manages to do that.
Only problem is that it is ill-formatted.
[image]

Comment: yes, it is. and it is a working link. During edition I wanted to remove that link.

Comment: There's a hidden input on the page, `<input type="hidden" id="55446907-only-allow-inform-moderator-flagging" value="true">` which I guess means they wanted you to flag this for either plagiarism or self-promotion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a post is otherwise unsalvageable (e.g. because it's SPAM because it includes undisclosed self-promotion), trying to edit it for formatting it's the wrong action.

[You shouldn't edit out SPAM](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110030/should-spam-posts-be-edited). Those posts need to be flagged.